# Is it possible to fake the build.prop?

Tags: android, android-studio

When an app asks for example:

`Build.MODEL.contains("samsung")`

it will get the information out of the build.prop file right?
Is it somehow possible to redirect sutch commands to another "fake" file? 
Or is it somehow possible to block the accsess of an app to this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your device is rooted you should be able to edit the properties file directly:

https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1948558

Or if you roll your own AOSP build you can set those to what ever you need or want but you'll need to flash the build on to your device.

Comment: My aim was to redirect a functioncall to another file not the "real" build.prop so I dont need to edit it. Im a compleatly beginner. My problem is when I edit the build.prop too mutch my device just stuck in bootloop. I want to find a fancier way to hide/fake this information.

Comment: You can't do that unless you modify Android (By building your own from the AOSP).